# How to get multivalue lookup column items from sharepoint list to infopath?

Tags: infopath, lookup-column, multiple-values

I am on a project.

I have a list that have 2 columns. One is the title, other is a multiple value look up column from another list. Everything is ok, working well. And call it ListA.

BUT, i am creating a infopath form to display something. I already get 3 different list items in this form. I can get ListA's items but this multiple value column. Why ?

When i try to modify data source of this list, this multi value column is missing. Why is that missing ?

Any quick help appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I did not understand what is "multiple value lookup column from another field". I understood, also having consulted your previous question, that you want Multiple-Selection List Box on lookup field.

It works for me. If you want help in particular problem, you should provide more details and in more clear terms  how to reproduce it.

Having created and filled AnotherList

[image: AnotherList]

as well as created athe ListA and Infopath form for it.

in the Infopath Designer 2010 in edit mode of ListA Sharepoint List dorm for ListA I inserted Multiple-Selection List Box

[image]

having data-connected it to the column Title of ListA

[image]

[image]

filled 2 items into ListA having selected 2nd and 3d choice for first item and first choice for 2nd item

[image]

Here is screenshot of run-time 2nd item of ListA in browser:

[image]

**Update:**
Items are gotten as whole and just one of representing display field from it is selected to be rendered.
As such I answered about multiple values column.
So, one lookups multiple items not multiple columns from the same (already lookuped) item.

If you want to change the question to about getting values of multiple-columns and clarify there whay you want and why, then ask another question, don't change the original one.

Comment: Thanks for advice. But its not the problem. In here, at your 3rd picture, there should be lookup field (Allowed mutliple values) but its not there. This is my problem ://

Comment: What's the difference. I added Col2 field and updated screenshots. First, lookup field is the one that references not being referenced (like you are trying to insist). 2nd, there are no multi-column lookup fields. 3d, it is senseless since it is not field but whole item of another field which being gotten (by getting its ID or another identifying lookup value ) and then you choose which one display field to show.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem. I have a multi-value lookup field in a Sharepoint as such:
Projects which allows multiple values from another list of Users.

Simple enough, I create a project and designate Users to execute it.

When I pulled it into InfoPath it automatically created a data connection to the Projects List and another to the User list. However, the User list data connection was only pulling over a Title and ID. After futzing around with it for an hour I finally decided to build a new data connection to Users (as Users1) and I was able to pick the fields I needed. Hope this helps!